# Blocking main website of facebook and making m.facebook.com available on windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, blocking, facebook

I have been searching about the blocking facebook on my computer over the hour, but I am getting exactly the same method over all the webpages.

1. Change settings on Windows defender to make host file an exception
2. Run notepad in admin mode and add **127.0.0.1 m.facebook.com**
3. Save the changes and check.

It perfectly works for **m.facebook.com** but this blocks only the mobile view of the facebook. What I want is **to unblock mobile view and block the main site.** Can any one show me the way?

**EDIT**

Currently I am not able to block the main site what so ever. I used **facebook.com** only as well instead of **m.facebook.com**

**And strange case:**

I tested as below

```
127.0.0.1 yahoo.com -> This blocks yahoo.com but not www.yahoo.com
127.0.0.1 www.yahoo.com -> This doesn't block www.yahoo.com
```

**P.S** I don't want to block the website for whole network. Instead want to do it just on my laptop

Thank you for help.

Comment: What happens when you leave m. alone and block facebook.com and www.facebook.com as you did above?

Comment: @Paul Please refer to the edit. Thank you for response

Comment: Do you use a modem ?

Comment: @ManuJacob I use cable net from router.

Comment: Where this router located, at your home or somewhere else ?

Comment: @ManuJacob Home. Few rooms away :D Does that matter?

Comment: Can you get to the router's settings from your computer ? I have a modem here. I can get to its settings by entering 192.168.1.1 in any browser. Is it possible for you to do anything like this ?

Comment: @ManuJacob Yes I can. And please see my new edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18182/discussion-between-manu-jacob-and-nabin).

Comment: Please come to chat.